# Greenhouse Job Board integration using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying to implement a Greenhouse's Job Board.

I made a simple ajax request from Greenhouse using `jsonp` as `dataType`, as they explains here: https://developers.greenhouse.io/job-board.html

```
var greenhouseUrl = 'https://boards.greenhouse.io/vaulttec';

$.ajax({
    url: greenhouseUrl,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I don't know why but it's not working at all. `console.log` only throws me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Some help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If this code is correct, it looks like you are trying to load the home page and not using a valid api url.

Comment: You are not using the API endpoint, if you visit the page you link you will see the endpoints start with :  `https://api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/` and then you need to add the appropriate values for the placeholders like  `{board_token}`